# Fourier transform of modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: integration, special-functions, fourier-transform, bessel-functions

Does anyone have any suggestions for performing the following Fourier transform:

I = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K_0(a \sqrt{x^2+1}) e^{i kx} dx $

where $K_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: For those interested, I have found the answer in the mean time in the Bateman table of integrals. It is given by, $I(k) = (\frac{\pi}2) (k^2 + a^2)^{-1/2} e^{-(k^2 + a^2)^{1/2}}$.

Answer (score 7):

From the integral representation [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E10)
$$K_{0}\left(z\right)=\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp%
\left(-t-\frac{z^{2}}{4t}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}$$, the integral can be written as
$$ I(k)=\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-t-\frac{a^{2}}{4t}\right)\frac{dt}{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(ikx-\frac{a^2x^2}{4t}\right)\,dx$$With the Fourier transform of the Gaussian,
$$ I(k)=\tfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-t\left(1+\frac{k^2}{a^2}\right)-\frac{a^{2}}{4t}\right)\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}} $$
Now, with $u=t\left(1+\frac{k^2}{a^2}\right)$ in this expression, 
$$I(k)=\tfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{a} \left(1+\frac{k^2}{a^2}\right)^{-\tfrac{1}{4}}\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-u-\tfrac{k^2+a^2}{4u}\right)\,\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}$$
Recognizing the integral representation for $K_{-\tfrac{1}{2}}\left(\sqrt{k^2+a^2}\right)$ , the result quoted in the comment follows.

Comment: That's the integral representation I was thinking of when I read the question. +1

Comment: nice $\left(+1\right)$