# An integral related to the Quaternionic Fourier transform of Poisson kernel

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, harmonic-analysis, quaternions

I am attempting to compute the Quaternion Fourier transform (QFT) of the Poisson kernel in upper-half space. Specifically, I would like to compute

$$
\mathcal{QFT_r}\{p\}(u,v; s) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{s}{2\pi(x^2 + y^2 + s^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
e^{-2\pi \mathbf{i} x u} e^{-2\pi \mathbf{j} y v} \;dx\;dy,
$$
for $s > 0$, where $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$ are the standard quaternions such that $\mathbf{i} \mathbf{j} = \mathbf{k}$.

Wolfram alpha has gotten me so far as
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{s}{2\pi(x^2 + y^2 + s^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
e^{-2\pi \mathbf{i} x u} e^{-2\pi \mathbf{j} y v} \;dx\;dy = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{2s|u|K_1\left(2\pi |u|\sqrt{y^2 + s^2}\right)}{\sqrt{y^2 + s^2}}
\cos(2\pi y v) \;dy,
$$

where $K_1$ is the [$1^{st}$ order modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1), and may be written as the integral equation
$$
  K_1(z) = z \int_{0}^{+\infty} 
  \frac{\cos(t)}{(t^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} \; dt.
$$
It may also be worth noting the identity
$$
K_0(2\pi s|v|) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{s}{2\sqrt{y^2 + s^2}}
\cos(2\pi y v) \;dy,
$$
where $K_0$ is the $0^{th}$order modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Unfortunately I do not have significant reason to believe that there will be a nice closed form of this integral, but I am hoping some further insight could be provided.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER:** *This is nothing other than the Fourier transform of the standard Poisson kernel on $\mathbb{R}^3_{+}$. A standard identity of the modified Bessel function of the second kind,*
$$
K_{\frac{1}{2}}(\xi) = \left(\frac{2\xi}{\pi}\right)^{-\frac12}\exp(-\xi),
$$

*makes that clear at the end of the following computation. So the final answer is simply $\exp(-2\pi s \sqrt{u^2 + v^2})$. If you instead consider the un-factored Quaternion Fourier transform of the Poisson kernel, that is,*
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}p(\mathbf{x};s)
\exp(-2\pi(\mathbf{i}ux_1 + \mathbf{j}vx_2))\;d\mathbf{x},
$$

*then this should no longer be the standard FT of $p$.*

*All that being said, this is a computation of the Fourier transform of the Poisson kernel I haven't seen before, so perhaps it is worth leaving up here.*

This integral is possible after some wrestling with integral tables and stumbling across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421990/fourier-transform-of-%20modified-bessel-function-of-the-second-kind) related post which makes heavy use of the integral representation:

$$
  K_{\nu}(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{\nu}
  \int_{t = 0}^{+\infty} \exp\left(-t - \frac{z^2}{4t}\right) \frac{d t}{t^{\nu+1}}
  \text{ when $|ph(z)| < \pi/4$} \label{eq:Knu1},
$$

specifically for $\nu = 1$ and $\nu = 1/2$, and $z = \sqrt{y^2 + 1}$.

Starting from
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{2s|u|K_1\left(2\pi |u|\sqrt{y^2 + s^2}\right)}{\sqrt{y^2 + s^2}}
\exp(\mathbf{j} 2\pi y v) \;dy,
$$

we first let $a = 2\pi |u|$, $k = 2\pi v$, and set $s = 1$ for simplicity, to give
$$
\frac{a}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{K_1\left(a\sqrt{y^2 + 1}\right)}{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}}
\exp(\mathbf{j} ky) \;dy.
$$

Now substitute the integral representation for $K_1$ given above and using the same technique as in the other post referenced we have:

\begin{align*}
  \frac{a}{\pi} \int_{y=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{K_1(a \sqrt{y^2 + 1})}{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}} 
  e^{\mathbf{j} k y }\;dy &= 
  \frac{a}{4\pi} \int_{y=-\infty}^{+\infty} 
\frac{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}}{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}}
    \left(\int_{t=0}^{+\infty} \exp\left(-t - \frac{a^2(y^2 + 1)}{4t}\right)
    \frac{dt}{t^2}\right)
    e^{\mathbf{j} k y }\;dy\\
    &=  \frac{a}{4\pi}
    \int_{t=0}^{+\infty} \exp\left(-t - \frac{a^2}{4t}\right)
    \frac{dt}{t^2}
    \int_{y = -\infty}^{+\infty}
    \exp\left(\mathbf{j} k y\right)\exp\left(-\frac{a^2y^2 }{4t}\right)\;dy \\
    &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}
    \int_{t=0}^{+\infty} \exp\left(-t\left(1 + \frac{k^2}{a^2}\right)
     - \frac{a^2}{4t}\right)
    \frac{dt}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}},
\end{align*}

where the last equality comes from computing the 1D Fourier transform of
the Gaussian. Making the substitution
$\omega = t\left(1 + \frac{k^2}{a^2}\right)$ and using the identity

\begin{align*}
K_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sqrt{a^2 + k^2}\right)
  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(a^2 + k^2\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}
  \int_{\omega = 0}^{+\infty} \exp\left(-\omega - \frac{a^2 + k^2}{4\omega}\right) 
  \frac{d\omega}{\omega^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{align*}

finally yields

\begin{align*}
  \frac{a}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{K_1(a \sqrt{y^2 + 1})}{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}} 
  e^{\mathbf{j} k y }\;dy &= 
  \frac{\sqrt{2}(a^2 + k^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{\sqrt{\pi}} 
  K_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sqrt{a^2 + k^2}\right).
\end{align*}

With some re-substitution and an easy u-sub to write this for any $s > 0$, the final result I computed is

\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{QFT}_r\{p\}(u,v;s) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} 
  \frac{s}{2\pi\left(x^2 + y^2 + s^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} 
  e^{-2\pi \mathbf{i} x u} e^{-2\pi \mathbf{j} y v}\;dx dy\\
  &= 2s^{\frac{1}{2}} (u^2 + v^2)^{\frac{1}{4}} 
  K_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(2\pi s \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}\right)
\end{align*}